# How to reboot the Aurora Instance with Failover using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Below is my working code already (rebooting the Aurora RDS instance on Lambda without failover).

```
import boto3
region = 'ap-northeast-1'
instances = 'myAuroraInstanceName'
rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rds.reboot_db_instance(
                 DBInstanceIdentifier=instances

                )
    print('Rebooting your DB Instance: ' + str(instances))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a second to read [the documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.reboot_db_instance). It's extremely clear from the documentation how you specify the failover setting:

```
rds.reboot_db_instance(
             DBInstanceIdentifier=instances,
             ForceFailover=True
            )
```